# why "onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)" is not working?

Tags: android, menu

i have implemented menu in android with two menu items "edit" and "delete". I can see my Menu Item but when i click either of them nothing happens. here is my implementation.

```
public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.edit:
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "edit clicked", 5).show();
             return true;

         case R.id.delete:
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "delete clicked", 5).show();
             return true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } //end switch
 }//end method
```

edit and delete are the id's of item in menu.xml.
i will appreciate any help...

Comment: This looks fine (aside from indentation). Post your menu XML and the other options menu methods that you have overridden.

Comment: Put a Toast in the switch case's default block too.. It will help you isolate the issue.

Comment: Can you post more of this class?  Does your class inherit from Activity? If so, are you missing an @Override annotation?

Answer (score 2):

Change the method name to onOptionsItemSelected (with an s after Option).